# Dialing with Intent.ACTION_CALL stopps at # in phone number

Tags: android

I try to dial the phone number 03012345,1234,#31#,98765
(callthrough with a FRITZ!Box)

"03012345" is the phone number of the FRITZ!Box, "," are dial pauses, "#31#" is a prefix to show my own phone number to the callee and "98765" is the phonenumber of the callee.

```
String phonenumber = "03012345,1234,#31#,98765";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phonenumber)));
```

On my smartphone, everything works fine, but some user reported to me, that their smartphones stopp dialing after the first #. But when they dial from contacts, it works.

Maybe, `Uri.parse` splits the phone number? Or is there another way to dial such a phone number?

Comment: may be there is something in  logcat ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution:

```
String phonenumber = "03012345,1234,#31#,98765"; // , = pauses
encodedPhonenumber = URLEncoder.encode(phonenumber, "UTF-8");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedPhonenumber)));
```

You simply have to encode the phone number.

Comment: Thanks!!! The only answer that worked for me. Dont' forget that you must not encode the "tel:" string or it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Really late on the answer, but another way that this can be done is with `Uri.Builder`. Using `encodedPath()` assumes that the string you're passing is already encoded, so it will be added to the `Uri` as is:

```
final String phonenumber = "03012345,1234,#31#,98765";
final Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("tel").encodedPath(phonenumber).build();
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri));
```