# What is the activity class name of the Android native phone app dial activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, app-inventor

I'm developing an app with the App Inventor for Android.

I want the open the native phone app of my android phone by clicking on a button. I try does do something similar like in [this tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/maptour.html) where Google Maps is opened by clicking on a list item.

For that i need the following information:

Action: `android.intent.action.DIAL`

ActivityPackage: **???**

ActivityClass: **???**

I guess the package is `com.android.phone`. But I also need the `ActivityClass`. I tried to google it but couldn't find anything about it.

**EDIT:** Turns out that the App Inventor provides a way to make a direct phone call (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: refer this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174240/dialing-with-intent-action-call-stopps-at-in-phone-number

Comment: As I said, I'm using the App Inventor, not coding in Java. So I need the class name.

Comment: for your device you can read logcat though code.and while dialing number which activity is lunching you can check it.

Comment: How can I read the logcat? Do I have to use Eclipse for that?

Comment: I only get the package name in the logcat, not the activity class name.

Comment: try this one-    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
Iterator i = l.iterator();
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
while(i.hasNext()) {
  ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
  try {
    CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
  }catch(Exception e) {
    //Name Not FOund Exception
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **App Inventor** you can use the [Phone Call component](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/social.html#PhoneCall) to dial the phone and make a call

> PhoneCall is a non-visible component that makes a phone call to the number specified in the PhoneNumber property, which can be set either in the Designer or Blocks Editor. You can use the MakePhoneCall method to make a phone call programatically from your app.
>
> To directly specify the phone number, set the PhoneNumber property to a Text with the specified digits (for example, "6505551212"). The number can be formatted with hyphens, periods, and parentheses; they are ignored. You can't include spaces in the number.

In case you try do do something else, these Activity Starter links could help:

- [Activity Starter Project by Gene & Tony](http://www.taiic.com/projects/activity-starter-intents/), [source v 0.74](http://code.google.com/p/taiic/downloads/detail?name=ActivityStarter_v0_74.zip)
- [Activity Starter & Intents Tracker, Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmF-kDWbm3w4dHNnQWtWLUR5Nkc2TFk2ZjRPRWRqM0E)
- [App Inventor Activity Starter App with more than 100 examples of activities](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_mletsch80.AppInvActivityStarter)

Comment: Yes, just found it out myself. Didn't know that it was so easy to achieve that. I updated my question and added a screenshot with a possible solution from the blocks editor.

Answer (score 0):

try this for reading logs-

```
 try {
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

          StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
          String line = "";
          while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
          }
          TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          tv.setText(log.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```